# Не отображаються данные на вьюшке (AngularJS + Web API)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Вообщем проблема следующая. Есть вьюшка Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="testApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Users</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
            testApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
            {
                 $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/users'}).then(function success(response)
                 {
                    $scope.users = response.data;
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div id="createBlock">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>  
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td>{{user.Name}}</td>           
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

При запуске приложения всё нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот если прописать запрос к самому контроллеру, то данные не отображаються:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас недосуг проверять, но есть подозрение, что во втором случае вот эта строчка: `$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'api/users'})` обращается к адресу `/Home/Index/api/users`.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Спасибо за помощь.